# Can we have functional return type condition check in guard?

Tags: swift, conditional-statements, guard

```
    func getListCount () -> [String]{

        return listArray
    }

    guard getListCount().count >= 1 else {
        //handle else condition
        print("Please add Items or set Alert")
        return;
    }
```

Do your stuff related to listArray.

Comment: Please explain better what you mean

Comment: I failed to put return in guard its throws an error "guard' body must not fall through, consider using a 'return' or 'throw'". I wounder can we do in above format!  using function return types count!